# Fixed points of representational bifunctors

Tags: haskell, ghc, coercion, fixpoint-combinators, bifunctor

Edward Kmett's experimental [roles package](https://github.com/ekmett/roles/blob/master/src/Data/Roles.hs) offers various utilities for lifting coercions, some of which I've pasted at the end of this question. The key class in the package is

```
class Representational (t :: k1 -> k2) where
  -- | An argument is representational if you can lift a coercion of the argument into one of the whole
  rep :: Coercion a b -> Coercion (t a) (t b)
```

Given the type

```
newtype Fix p a = In {out :: p (Fix p a) a}
```

I'm hoping to write something like

```
instance Representational p => Representational (Fix p)
```

I believe the following should work, except for one missing piece. I'm also a bit concerned that `bar` may be strict enough to throw everything into an infinite loop.

```
-- With {-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds, ScopedTypeVariables, etc.)
import Data.Type.Coercion
import Data.Coerce
import Data.Roles

instance Representational p => Representational (Fix p) where
  rep :: forall a b . Coercion a b -> Coercion (Fix p a) (Fix p b)
  rep x = sym blah . quux . baz . blah
    where
      bar :: Coercion (p (Fix p a)) (p (Fix p b))
      bar = rep (rep x)

      baz :: Coercion (p (Fix p a) a) (p (Fix p b) a)
      baz = eta bar

      quux :: Coercion (p (Fix p b) a) (p (Fix p b) b)
      quux = undefined -- ?????????

      blah :: forall x . Coercion (Fix p x) (p (Fix p x) x)
      blah = Coercion
```

#### Bits and pieces of `roles`

```
eta :: forall (f :: x -> y) (g :: x -> y) (a :: x). 
       Coercion f g -> Coercion (f a) (g a)

instance Representational Coercion
instance Representational f => Representational (Compose f)
```

Comment: @Cactus, there is `Data.Type.Coercion.sym`, but I'm not sure what you mean; the `a` and `b` in the type of `baz` are tied to the ones that ride in on `x` (scoped type variables); can you clarify?

Comment: Also, I added a remark noting some concern about my `bar` implementation—it may never terminate.... I'm beginning to think I may be stuck with some ugly `unsafeCoerce`, or perhaps that I've under-constrained `p` and need to rethink this.

Comment: All in all, I think you would need some kind of higher-kinded version of `Compose` (with its own `Representational` instance) to break up `p (Fix p a) a)` into `Compose' p (Fix p) a a`; but that `Representational` instance would be implemented by `unsafeCoerce` anyway...

Comment: @Cactus, I think I might have figured it out. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The problem, as stated, cannot be solved, because the fact that `p` is `Representational` (or even `Phantom`) does *not* imply that `p (Fix p a)` is representational. Here's a counterexample:

```
data NF a b where
  NF :: NF a ()

instance Representational NF where
  rep _ = Coercion
```

Clearly, `NF a` is never representational; we cannot possibly implement

```
rep :: Coercion x y -> Coercion (NF a x) (NF a y)
```

(regardless of the choice of `a`) because `NF a x` is only inhabited when `x ~ ()`.

Therefore, we need a more refined notion of representational bifunctor to make this idea sensible. `unsafeCoerce` is almost certainly necessary to implement it in any case, because digging through an infinite chain of `Coercion`s would take an infinite amount of time, and `Coercion`s can't be matched lazily.

One (possibly valid?) concept, which I just [suggested on GitHub](https://github.com/ekmett/roles/issues/1):

```
class Birepresentational t where
  birep :: Coercion p q -> Coercion a b -> Coercion (t p a) (t q b)

instance Birepresentational f => Representational (Fix f) where
  rep (x :: Coercion a b) = (birep :: forall p q x y . Coercion p q -> Coercion x y -> Coercion (f p x) (f q y))
                            (unsafeCoerce x :: Coercion (Fix f a) (Fix f b))
                            x `seq` unsafeCoerce x
```

The point of forcing application of `birep` is to (hopefully) make sure that it actually terminates, and therefore its type can be trusted.